# S3 access denied error for a mediaconvert job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-media-convert

I am trying to follow the instructions from this AWS documentation to create a AWS MediaConvert job with a **KMS key for server side encryption**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/implementing-server-side-encryption.html

The job keeps giving me error 
*Unable to write to output file [s3://{path to my output bucket}/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MGhls_264_00001.ts]: [Failed to write data: Access Denied]*

I understand that the job is unable to access the output bucket. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Here are some of the links I referred
[What permissions S3 needs for AWS MediaConverter to have access to write files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288790/what-permissions-s3-needs-for-aws-mediaconverter-to-have-access-to-write-files)
https://repost.aws/questions/QUWX3fYP2CT7eychPQqiwHJQ/unable-to-write-to-output-file

Here is my policy snapshot for my Media Converter Role
[image: Media_Convert_Default_Role]
Mediaconvert_default_role_* policy
[image]

Can someone help me troubleshoot the issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your Mediaconvert_default_role_* is trying to grant KMS, IAM and STS permissions to an Amazon S3 bucket.
These are not permission's you can allow on a bucket itself.

Are you using the default S3 managed key or a KMS key that is managed by AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS)?

If you are using AWS KMS key you need to add an inline policy to your role
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/granting-permissions-for-mediaconvert-to-access-encrypted-s3-buckets.html